# How to get bazel rule execution start time?

Tags: bazel

Our bazel builds sometimes stuck and get timeouts, so we lose all build logs when VM is killed. To find the cause, we want to use [Build event protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html) to see which rules started to get executed, but did not finish (usually these are memory-eager tests).

[This graph](https://docs.bazel.build/assets/bep-graph.svg) from [official docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html#the-build-event-protocol-by-example) shows that `TargetConfigured` and `TargetCompleted` events are the only events between rule start and finish.

But in reality bazel configures all targets at the same time, so we cannot just subtract `TargetCompleted` time from `TargetConfigured` time.

Moreover, both events do not contain any timestamp. Here is the build event file from the [sample repo](https://github.com/MikhailTymchukFT/bazel-sandbox) (truncated):

```
    {"id":{"targetConfigured":{"label":"//:B"}},"children":[{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:B","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}}],"configured":{"targetKind":"java_binary rule","tag":["__JAVA_RULES_MIGRATION_DO_NOT_USE_WILL_BREAK__"]}}
    {"id":{"targetConfigured":{"label":"//:main"}},"children":[{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:main","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}}],"configured":{"targetKind":"java_library rule","tag":["__JAVA_RULES_MIGRATION_DO_NOT_USE_WILL_BREAK__"]}}
    {"id":{"targetConfigured":{"label":"//:step1"}},"children":[{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:step1","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}}],"configured":{"targetKind":"genrule rule"}}
    {"id":{"progress":{"opaqueCount":2}},"children":[{"progress":{"opaqueCount":3}},{"namedSet":{"id":"0"}}],"progress":{"stderr":"\r\u001b[1A\u001b[K\u001b[32mAnalyzing:\u001b[0m 3 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)\n\r\u001b[1A\u001b[K\u001b[32mINFO: \u001b[0mAnalyzed 3 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).\n\n\r\u001b[1A\u001b[K\u001b[32mINFO: \u001b[0mFound 3 targets...\n\n\r\u001b[1A\u001b[K\u001b[32m[0 / 1]\u001b[0m [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt\n"}}
    {"id":{"workspaceStatus":{}},"workspaceStatus":{"item":[{"key":"BUILD_EMBED_LABEL"},{"key":"BUILD_HOST","value":"mtymchuk"},{"key":"BUILD_TIMESTAMP","value":"1598888970"},{"key":"BUILD_USER","value":"mikhailtymchuk"}]}}
    {"id":{"namedSet":{"id":"0"}},"namedSetOfFiles":{"files":[{"name":"B.jar","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/B.jar","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]},{"name":"B","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/B","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
    {"id":{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:B","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}},"completed":{"success":true,"outputGroup":[{"name":"default","fileSets":[{"id":"0"}]}],"tag":["__JAVA_RULES_MIGRATION_DO_NOT_USE_WILL_BREAK__"],"importantOutput":[{"name":"B.jar","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/B.jar","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]},{"name":"B","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/B","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
    {"id":{"progress":{"opaqueCount":3}},"children":[{"progress":{"opaqueCount":4}},{"namedSet":{"id":"1"}}],"progress":{}}
    {"id":{"namedSet":{"id":"1"}},"namedSetOfFiles":{"files":[{"name":"libmain.jar","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libmain.jar","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
    {"id":{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:main","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}},"completed":{"success":true,"outputGroup":[{"name":"default","fileSets":[{"id":"1"}]}],"tag":["__JAVA_RULES_MIGRATION_DO_NOT_USE_WILL_BREAK__"],"importantOutput":[{"name":"libmain.jar","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libmain.jar","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
    {"id":{"progress":{"opaqueCount":4}},"children":[{"progress":{"opaqueCount":5}},{"namedSet":{"id":"2"}}],"progress":{}}
    {"id":{"namedSet":{"id":"2"}},"namedSetOfFiles":{"files":[{"name":"step1_output.txt","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/step1_output.txt","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
    {"id":{"targetCompleted":{"label":"//:step1","configuration":{"id":"f157fdcaf05e7672fa1bf535fbb2c3edb004ce9e9a7f6d84d9bf031454e2fb64"}}},"completed":{"success":true,"outputGroup":[{"name":"default","fileSets":[{"id":"2"}]}],"importantOutput":[{"name":"step1_output.txt","uri":"file:///private/var/tmp/_bazel_mikhailtymchuk/3bd90847b9f03e9e5c46f99d542eb754/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/step1_output.txt","pathPrefix":["bazel-out","darwin-fastbuild","bin"]}]}}
```

So, is it possible to extract target build start time from the build event protocol (or using another method)?

Answer (score 0):

On the console, if that helps, you should be able to get this information combining `--subcommands` (or `-s`) which prints commands as they are being executed. And `--show_timestamps` which adds timestamps to all messages emitted.

It's not the same as what you're asking for (which I am not sure adding time to build event protocol could be trivially achieved just by configuration), but it may help with the debugging quest.